# How to prove that closure of $(0,1]$ is $[0,1]$ and closure of $B$ = {$1/n | n∈N$} is $B$⋃{$0$}?

Tags: general-topology

I am not able to prove it using definition of closure .For example closure of $(0,1]$ must contain $(0,1]$ hence closure of $(0,1]$ must be subset of $[0,1]$ .But i am not able to prove or write down mathematically that it must be $[0,1]$ .

In case of second example , $B$ = {$1/n | n∈N$} ,  i don't understand why the closure will not be B itself ?Isn't complement of B a open set and hence B is closed ?

Topology here considered is usual topology on $R$.

The book i am following gives this example before it introduces limit points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One equivalent  definition is , $$\bar A=\{x \in X: x=\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n\;\text{with}\;a_n \in A, \forall n\}$$

- Here, $A=(0,1]$. Note that all points in $A$ are considered as a constant sequences, so certainly $(0,1] \subset \bar A$. On the otherhand, $1/n \in A$, so that $1/n \to 0 \in \bar A$. Hence $\bar A=[0,1]$
- Similarly, $\bar B=\{1/n\} \cup \{0\}$

Comment: Is sequential limit  allowed ?

Comment: Does not matter now since i figured out myself .

Comment: I accept your answer for your time